# Django admin filter using method

Tags: django-admin

How can make custom filter in django admin. I mean write a method do some calculation in it and add it to [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a class inheriting from django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter like as described at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking.